# Slow meta data with oracle database

Tags: oracle, performance, jvx

We have an oracle database with several schemes with a lot of tables and grants between the schemes.
The initial metadata select of jvx OracleDBAccess, takes about 1 minute.
Is there a possibility, to improve the speed of gathering the meta data?

I have a DBStorage, using the OracleDBAccess.

```
  DBStorage dbsContacts = new DBStorage();
  dbsContacts.setDBAccess(getDBAccess());
  dbsContacts.setWritebackTable("CONTACTS");
  dbsContacts.open();
```

First usage of the storage takes about 1 minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, be sure that your statement/query is not the problem. It's possible that the query is slow and you think that metadata queries are the problem.

Simply enable logging for: `com.sibvisions.rad.persist.jdbc` package

In your example, if this is the real use-case, the query shouldn't be a problem because it's a `select * from CONTACTS` (and some joins if your table has foreign keys).

Next, try to optimize metadata directly in your database:

```
purge dba_recyclebin;
DBMS_STATS.gather_dictionary_stats
DBMS_STATS.gather_fixed_objects_stats;
DBMS_STATS.GATHER_SYSTEM_STATS;
DBMS_STATS.GATHER_PROCESSING_RATE;
```

Above statemens will cleanup the metadata cache and recalculates statistics.

Additional information about [gather_dictionary_stats](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_dictionary_analyze_dbms_stats_statiistics.htm), [gather_fixed_objects_stats](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/post/fixed-objects-statistics-and-why-they-are-important), [gather_system_stats](https://www.dba-oracle.com/t_dbms_stats_gather_system_stats.htm)

Also a [similar question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/218801/oracle-12c-slow-query-to-tables-all-cons-columns-and-all-constraints) for Oracle 12c.